# DrawRect does not get called in a simple customized UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

In the code below, my drawRect method is never called. Note tht HypnosisView is inherited from UIView. Can some experts here help me out? Thanks a lot!

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// This code is never getting called.... 
    NSLog(@"in drawRect...");

    // Drawing code -- no need to post this since this function is not even getting called
}


@end
```

Below is the code I created the view and added it to the current window...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    CGRect wholeWindow = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460); //[window bounds];
    view = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:wholeWindow];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [window addSubview:view];

    [view setNeedsDisplay];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that `window` is `nil`. Make sure it's correctly bound in Interface Builder.

Comment: Rob, u r right. the 'window' is nil. Really appreciate ur help! I am not sure where to set the correct bound in the interface builder, but i checked the xib file, the main window has a referencing outlet to the controller file, "Hyposister App Delegate". Is this correct and if not how to fix this? Thanks a lot! //PS: i am new to this thing, pardon if i am making stupid mistakes :)

Comment: Rob, I did the following to initialize the 'window', and now the code is calling into subView's drawRect:    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
    
    view = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

Comment: Sorry that i still have questions, now that within my drawRect, nothing is drawn to the simulator. I've stepped into the code, everything seems normal, the core graphics context is not nil and the coordinates are within the screen. i am kinda running out of ideas...experts, please help me, thanks!!

Comment: Don't create your own UIWindow object. Just go into Interface Builder and Control-Drag from the Window to the Application Delegate and bind it to the "window" outlet.'

Comment: Thanks Rob! I tried what u mentioned, and also checked the existence of the outlet. and there is an outlet connecting windows to "Hypnosister App Delegate". Also, i just realized that without initializing my own window and without adding [self setNeedsDisplay] into my drawRect, the stuff is not drawing. i opened another question regarding this at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562971/simple-sub-uiview-is-not-drawing-although-drawrect-gets-called

Comment: rob (this is the favorite name i typed today!!) i removed outlet and reconnect it through the UIBuilder again, and now everything works!!! Now i dont need to initialize my own window.. Not sure where it went wrong, probably the UIBuilder itself... many many thanks to you, rob!

Comment: just adding notes for ppl who may have the same question later. Once the window frame in *.xib file is bound to the right outlet, no need to use setNeedsDisplay at all to get things work.